# Angular 2 - Passing data from child (within router-outlet) to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent container which contains the following:

```
<div id="pageContainer">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="title">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

I also have a service which I intend to use to pass data from the child component (within the router-outlet) to the parent component:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {


    emitChange(change: any) {

        return change;

    }

}
```

The child component calls the service method:

```
this.notificationsService.emitChange('Data from child');
```

And then the parent component assigns {{text}} from the service:

```
constructor(
        private notificationsService: NotificationsService
    ) {
        notificationsService.emitChange(
            text => {
                console.log(text);
            });
    }
```

But this still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Is there a text property in the parent component?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the data within the router outlet? Is there a specific reason? If you child component is used in your parent component you can just use an EventEmitter to pass the data.

Comment: @KerimEmurla because I have to show a notification box a large number of times throughout the app and it seems to make sense just to have to pass some data to it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use Subject to do this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {
  emitChange$: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  constructor() { }
  emit(value: any) {
    this.emitChange$.next(value);
  }
  get emitChange(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
    return (this.emitChange$ as BehaviorSubject<any>);
  }
}
```

in your child

```
this.notificationsService.emit('Data from child');
```

in parent

```
constructor(
    private notificationsService: NotificationsService
) {
    notificationsService.emitChange.subscribe(
        text => {
            console.log(text);
        });
}
```

btw, if your child component is use directly in parent component, you could using EventEmitter to communicate between them.

Comment: this is the initial value, did you call the function with this code `this.notificationsService.emit('Data from child');`

Comment: Yes I tried it on the child component on ngOnInit()